# Finding the right regex with Sed

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to replace some text in a `TSV` file using `sed`, but I am stuck with the regex.

Here is an example of a line:

```
0   NA  intron (NR_045393, intron 2 of 2)   intron (NR_045393, intron 2 of 2)   1089
```

I want to replace `intron (NR_045393, intron 2 of 2)` with `intron`, in order to get:

```
0   NA  intron  intron  1089
```

The pattern to match can be something like intron `(NM_001081221, intron 1 of 20)` or `intron (NM_144536, intron 5 of 15)`

My attempt to replace the pattern is as follow, but I am struggling to get this right

```
sed -i 's/intron.(\([a-zA-Z0-9\/_]\+\)\/,\s[a-zA-Z]\s[0-9]\s[a-z]\s[0-9])/intron/g' test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to remove anything in parentheses, just use

```
sed -e 's/([^)]*)//g'
```

To also remove the space preceding the left parenthesis, add it to the regex:

```
sed -e 's/ ([^)]*)//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -E -i 's/intron \([A-Z0-9_]+, intron [0-9]+ of [0-9]+\)/intron/g' test
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. I didn't know I could use space instead of \s